# CORS issue when making a POST api call to apache airflow server from Angular Frontend

Tags: python, angular, airflow

I'm trying to make POST call to http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/DAG_ID/dag_runs from Angular Frontend.

Got this Error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/pipeline-al-manual/dag_runs' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Apache Airflow is running on localhost:8080, Angular project is running on localhost:4200.

I cannot enable cors in the airflow experimental API. Are there any solutions to overcome that issue?

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4804

Any solutions to this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to make sure `Cors` is enabled on the endpoint you are accessing and you must also include the typical cors headers in your request : `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` , `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` depending on what you allow to be performed.

Comment: I'm actually using the Airflow Experimental API. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py. There is no CORS enabled for the endpoints. Do you have any idea how can I achieve it while calling the endpoint from Angular?

Comment: I actually resolved this issue by using a reverse proxy in angular. Refer to : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1MUmTjYKH8&t=202s

Comment: I am also having similar issue, how did you guys solve this?

Comment: I tried lot of things and finally ended up updating app.py in www folder to include cors for flask. Not sure if this is good but did not find any other way to do it.